# Line Break in VBA and whether it is a volatile function

Tags: excel, vba

1. How do I add a Line Break (<kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Enter</kbd>) into this set of codes? My end result should be something like:

   ```
   Text 1
   Text 2
   Text 3
   ```

   Not

   ```
   Text 1 Text 2 Text 3
   ```
2. Next, just a simple question, is this set of UDF codes considered a **volatile function**?

   ```vb
   Function MYVLOOKUP(pValue As String, pWorkRng As Range, pIndex As Long)
       Dim rng As Range
       Dim xResult As String
       xResult = ""
       For Each rng In pWorkRng
           If rng = pValue Then
               xResult = xResult & " " & rng.Offset(0, pIndex - 1)
           End If
       Next
       MYVLOOKUP = xResult
   End Function
   ```

Comment: `& vbcrlf` is one way.

Comment: Hey mark, i've tried inserting this into the " " part of the code, it doesn't work though.

Comment: `xResult = xResult & " " & vbcrlf & rng.Offset(0, pIndex - 1)`

Comment: `vbLf` is the actual Alt-Enter character in the Range.Value

Comment: Hey Patrick, thanks! vbLF worked just fine :)

Comment: Looking at your UDF, `TEXTJOIN` will do this if you have office 365.

Comment: ? ASC(vbLf) gives me 10 in the Immediate window. My preference is vbCr which is equivalent to vbCrLf (both return Chr(13)) and hasn't let me down for use in MsgBoxes. But when I want to write to a cell I use Chr(10) and when that cell is in a Word table I use Chr(11). Split("Me" & vbLf & "You", vbLf) does give me the same result. But what advantage do I get from using vbLf while I have to remember all the time that it stands for Chr(10)? There probably also is a vb enumeration for Chr(11) but why do I need to learn it?

Comment: Just a side question though, is this UDF a volatile function? And how do you tell if it is or not?

Comment: @Variatus `vbCrLf` is not an equivalent to `vbCr` simply because it's two characters and `vbCr` is one. `Asc()` returns the ASCII code of the first character in the string. The line separator that Excel recognizes inside cells is `vbLf`. You have to use that if you want line breaks inside cells. There is no difference between `vbLf` and the result of `Chr(10)`, aside from the fact that one is a constant and the other is a function call. You use `vbLf` because it's more readable than the [magic number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magic_number_(programming)) of 10.

Comment: @JoshNg You did not [declare](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.application.volatile) your function as volatile. Hence, it isn't.